# Need help installing Java 8 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to upgrade to: Java 8 Update 66, from Java 6, on my Mac running Mac OS X 10.10.5.  I downloaded the Java Update .dmg file: re-8u66-macosx-x64.dmg.  When I run the installer I get the message it installed properly.  When I confirmed the install via the FireFox Browser at this URL:
https://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
It reports:
**Congratulations!
You have the recommended Java installed (Version 8 Update 66).**

However, If I open a terminal window and enter: java -version
It reports:
**java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)**

Can someone please explain what is going on here?  Do I need to update a link somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: How many Java executables are there and in which directories ?

Comment: Delete old versions of java from your installation folder. Make sure your jre and jdk are same versions, bit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PATH variable, and make sure that the java directories in the path match the directories in your computer. It should be the bin folder of the JAVA_HOME environment directory. Also check that JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to the jdk folder of your java installation.

Answer (score 0):

There's two option based on my experience to fix this issue, fisrt uninstalled the java on your computer and reinstalled using the latest version.

Second, run a different version of Java, either specify the full path, or use the *java_home tool*:

List your installed java version:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

In this case you are using java 8 so you can run command
`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 --exec javac -version`

If you want to make easy to switch your java version you can create alias in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias java6="export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6);echo 'using Java 6'"
alias java8="export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8);echo 'using Java 8'"
```

Hope it help